# concat two dataframes and exclude overlapping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I'm trying to concat two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

**Input**

```
        name   age   hobby   married
index
0       jack   20    hockey  yes
1       ben    19    chess   no
2       lisa   30    golf    no
```

```
        name   age    hobby      job
index
0       jack   20     hockey     student
1       anna   34     football   finance
2       dan    26     golf       retail
```

which I want to match on multiple columns, so let's say `['name', 'age']`, to get `df`:

**Output**

```
        name   age   hobby     married   job
index
0       jack   20    hockey    yes       student
1       ben    19    chess     no        /
2       lisa   30    golf      no        /
3       anna   34    football  /         finance
4       dan    26    golf      /         retail
```

Is it possible to do this by using concat? Because I can't find out how to match the list of keys to avoid the overlapping rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
df1.set_index(['name', 'age'])\
   .combine_first(df2.set_index(['name', 'age']))\
   .reset_index()\
   .fillna('/')
```

Output:

```
   name  age     hobby      job married
0  anna   34  football  finance       /
1   ben   19     chess        /      no
2   dan   26      golf   retail       /
3  jack   20    hockey  student     yes
4  lisa   30      golf        /      no
```

Let's use intrinsic data alignment in pandas by setting the index to columns you want to "join" on then use `combine_first` the dataframes.

Comment: @gardangerous Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
In [1077]: res = df1.merge(df2, on=['name', 'age'], how='outer')
In [1079]: res['hobby'] = res.hobby_x.combine_first(res.hobby_y)

In [1081]: res.drop(['hobby_x', 'hobby_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [1082]: res
Out[1082]: 
   name  age married      job     hobby
0  jack   20     yes  student    hockey
1   ben   19      no      NaN     chess
2  lisa   30      no      NaN      golf
3  anna   34     NaN  finance  football
4   dan   26     NaN   retail      golf
```